# Divide the page in equal parts, under a navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar on top of my page, and i want divide the rest of the screen to 4 equal parts where i will load some data in each one of those four. How can i divide it UNDER the navbar?

(here is the code)

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" style="font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;">
  <img src="gym3.png" style="width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="callmeplease()">
  <a href=#><label style="color:#42f44b; border-radius: 25px;" >Welcome,</label> <?php echo $compName ?> |</a>
  <a href="http://localhost/testbench/workfile.php?choice=3" style="border-radius: 25px;">Events |</a>
  <a href="#contact" style="border-radius: 25px;">Customers |</a>
  <a href="#about" style="border-radius: 25px;">Balance |</a>
  <a href="http://localhost/testbench/workfile.php?choice=5" style='float:right; margin-right:10px;' style="border-radius: 25px;">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i havent tried yet, i just dont even have an idea how to not take into consideration the navbar

Comment: you can put navbar and columns into the same parent div

Comment: and then? will this fix the problem?

Comment: Have a look at Zurb's Foundation Grid - 
http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html

Comment: @Paulie_D already tried, after running some code that i found from google, the screen got divided, but the parts moved the screen down, so u had to scroll. I asked what in particular should i do when i have a navbar

Comment: post what youi tried :) and explain how it is different from the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
/*--CSS--*/


    div#custom-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    height: 90vh!important;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->


<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
 <body>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" style="font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;">
    <img src="gym3.png" style="width:50px; height:50px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="callmeplease()">
    <a href=#><label style="color:#42f44b; border-radius: 25px;" >Welcome,</label> <?php echo $compName ?> |</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/testbench/workfile.php?choice=3" style="border-radius: 25px;">Events |</a>
    <a href="#contact" style="border-radius: 25px;">Customers |</a>
    <a href="#about" style="border-radius: 25px;">Balance |</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/testbench/workfile.php?choice=5" style='float:right; margin-right:10px;' style="border-radius: 25px;">Logout</a>
  </div>
  <div id="custom-div">
   <div class="box">
    <h1>My Data</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h1>My Data2</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h1>My Data3</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h1>My Data4</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend, thats what i was looking for :D

Comment: Welcome! Please click on upvote if you got the solution since this is a reward for user in this community.